# pyqt: how to put a border frame around a widget

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, qframe

I'm making some changes to an existing PyQt project.  The UI was created with Qt Designer.

The relevant part is a QWidget that displays text. I'm trying to put margins around the text. I'd think the simplest way to do this would be to put a border around the QWidget whose background color is the same as the QWidget's background (white).

The QWidget is on a QFrame.  I'd like to put a white border inside the QFrame and around the edge of the QWidget.  The closest I've come is to put short vertical and horizontal spacers around the QWidget, but that displays the underlying grey QFrame. I can't figure out how to make that white. I'd prefer leaving the frame grey and just add a white border around the QWidget.

Any pointers would be be appreciated.

EDIT:

The ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>EbookViewer</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="EbookViewer">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>920</width>
    <height>774</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>E-book Viewer</string>
  </property>
  <property name="windowIcon">
   <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
    <normaloff>:/images/viewer.png</normaloff>:/images/viewer.png</iconset>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="QTreeView" name="toc">
       <property name="focusPolicy">
        <enum>Qt::WheelFocus</enum>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
       </property>
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
        <item row="0" column="0" colspan="2">
         <widget class="QWidget" name="view_bg" native="true">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Maximum">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>0</width>
            <height>0</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true">background:white</string>
          </property>
          <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
           <property name="leftMargin">
            <number>200</number>
           </property>
           <property name="topMargin">
            <number>30</number>
           </property>
           <property name="rightMargin">
            <number>200</number>
           </property>
           <property name="bottomMargin">
            <number>30</number>
           </property>
           <item row="0" column="0">
            <widget class="DocumentView" name="view" native="true">
             <property name="minimumSize">
              <size>
               <width>0</width>
               <height>0</height>
              </size>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="0" column="2">
         <widget class="QScrollBar" name="vertical_scrollbar">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="1" column="1">
         <widget class="QScrollBar" name="horizontal_scrollbar">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="2" column="1" colspan="2">
         <widget class="QFrame" name="dictionary_box">
          <property name="frameShape">
           <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="frameShadow">
           <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
          </property>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
           <item>
            <widget class="QWebView" name="dictionary_view">
             <property name="minimumSize">
              <size>
               <width>0</width>
               <height>150</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="url">
              <url>
               <string>about:blank</string>
              </url>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QToolButton" name="close_dictionary_view">
             <property name="toolTip">
              <string>Close dictionary</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>...</string>
             </property>
             <property name="icon">
              <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
               <normaloff>:/images/window-close.png</normaloff>:/images/window-close.png</iconset>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="tool_bar">
   <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Preferred">
     <horstretch>0</horstretch>
     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
   </property>
   <property name="windowTitle">
    <string>toolBar</string>
   </property>
   <property name="movable">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="iconSize">
    <size>
     <width>32</width>
     <height>32</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="floatable">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>LeftToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
   <addaction name="action_back"/>
   <addaction name="action_forward"/>
   <addaction name="separator"/>
   <addaction name="action_open_ebook"/>
   <addaction name="action_copy"/>
   <addaction name="action_font_size_larger"/>
   <addaction name="action_font_size_smaller"/>
   <addaction name="action_table_of_contents"/>
   <addaction name="action_full_screen"/>
   <addaction name="separator"/>
   <addaction name="action_previous_page"/>
   <addaction name="action_next_page"/>
   <addaction name="separator"/>
   <addaction name="action_bookmark"/>
   <addaction name="action_reference_mode"/>
   <addaction name="separator"/>
   <addaction name="action_preferences"/>
   <addaction name="action_metadata"/>
   <addaction name="separator"/>
   <addaction name="action_print"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="tool_bar2">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
   <addaction name="action_find_next"/>
   <addaction name="action_find_previous"/>
  </widget>
  <action name="action_back">
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/images/back.png</normaloff>:/images/back.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Back</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_forward">
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/images/forward.png</normaloff>:/images/forward.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Forward</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_next_page">
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/images/next.png</normaloff>:/images/next.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Next page</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_previous_page">
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/images/previous.png</normaloff>:/images/previous.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Previous page</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_font_size_larger">
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/images/font_size_larger.png</normaloff>:/images/font_size_larger.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Font size larger</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_font_size_smaller">
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/images/font_size_smaller.png</normaloff>:/images/font_size_smaller.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Font size smaller</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_table_of_contents">
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/images/chapters.png</normaloff>:/images/chapters.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Table of Contents</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_metadata">
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/images/dialog_information.png</normaloff>:/images/dialog_information.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Metadata</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_open_ebook">
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/images/document_open.png</normaloff>:/images/document_open.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Open ebook</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_find_next">
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/images/arrow-down.png</normaloff>:/images/arrow-down.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Find next</string>
   </property>
   <property name="toolTip">
    <string>Find next occurrence</string>
   </property>
   <property name="shortcut">
    <string>F3</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_copy">
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/images/edit-copy.png</normaloff>:/images/edit-copy.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Copy to clipboard</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_preferences">
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/images/config.png</normaloff>:/images/config.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Preferences</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_reference_mode">
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/images/lookfeel.png</normaloff>:/images/lookfeel.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Reference Mode</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_bookmark">
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/images/bookmarks.png</normaloff>:/images/bookmarks.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Bookmark</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_full_screen">
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/images/page.png</normaloff>:/images/page.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Toggle full screen</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_print">
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/images/print.png</normaloff>:/images/print.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Print</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_find_previous">
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="../../../../resources/images.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/images/arrow-up.png</normaloff>:/images/arrow-up.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Find previous</string>
   </property>
   <property name="toolTip">
    <string>Find previous occurrence</string>
   </property>
   <property name="shortcut">
    <string>Shift+F3</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QWebView</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>QtWebKit/QWebView</header>
  </customwidget>
  <customwidget>
   <class>DocumentView</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>calibre/gui2/viewer/documentview.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources>
  <include location="../../../../resources/images.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Can't the internal QWidget inherit from QFrame too ?

Comment: There's not enough information in the code you posted. Please post the whole `ui` file generated by Qt Designer, not the python module generated by pyuic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your `QWidget` inside another `QWidget` with its background set to the same colour.

You can then use the layout of the parent `QWidget` to adjust the width of the margin on each side (this can all be done within Qt Designer).

**EDIT**

Here are the steps to take in Qt Designer to achieve this:

1. Select the frame widget containing the text widget and break its layout.
2. Add a new `QWidget` to the frame widget (you could name it
   "borderWidget").
3. Set the background colour of the border widget using the `styleSheet`
   property in the Property Editor: e.g. `background-color: white`. (nb: it might help if you temporarily set this to a contrasting colour so you can more easily see what's going on).
4. Drag and drop the text widget onto the border widget.
5. Select the border widget and set it's layout (e.g. "Lay Out in a
   Grid").
6. Select the frame widget and set it's layout (e.g. "Lay Out in a
   Grid").
7. Select the border widget. Go to the Layout section in the Property
   Editor. There you will see properties like `layoutTopMargin`,
   `layoutLeftMargin`, etc which can be used to adjust the size of the
   border.

Comment: The problem is that the existing QWidget automatically expands to fill the entire frame, so the new border QWidget is not visible. Also, how exactly do I put another widget inside? I drop a new widget on my QWidget and the new one is on top.  "Send to back" doesn't send the new one behind the old.

Comment: Similarly,  I can drop a new widget on the frame next to the old QWidget, but what do I do next so that the old is behind the new and can have its size adjusted?

Comment: Aha - if I cut old widget, put new widget in place, the paste old, I have old on top of new.  Now I need to be able to set background color of new and figure out how to adjust sizes from the program.

Comment: almost there. I'd like the borderWidget to completely fill the frame (which may change in size at runtime) and the existing inner widget to expand to the border (at the moment I have a set minimumSize for both widgets). How to?

Comment: @foosion. 1. Select the frame and set its layout margins to zero. 2. Select the inner widget, and clear the `sizePolicy` in the Property Editor (there's a little arrow button on the right).

Comment: The border is to the left margin, but there's a big gap on the right. sizePolicy of border is[Maximum, Maximum, 0, 0] and inner is greyed (after pushing little arrow button).   The inner has a class name and in the code that class is inherited from QWebView. Code includes `self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)); self._size_hint = QSize(510, 680); self.to_bottom = False`