# pyqt: controlling a border widget

Tags: python, pyqt

In [pyqt: how to put a border frame around a widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942268/pyqt-how-to-put-a-border-frame-around-a-widget) I created a border around a widget.  I'd now like to be able to control that border from the underlying program.

1) The base widget has a class name in Qt Designer and uses that class name in the program.  How do I give a class name to my border widget?

2) I've set background color and margins in Qt Designer for the border widget.  How do I set these in the program (overriding the Qt Designer settings)?

Comment: btw: you accepted my answer in your previous question on this topic, but it's not clear from your latter comments whether it's completely solved. Do you need any further help?

Comment: I do need further help.  If I set a relatively narrow border, then the widget does not extend to the right margin. thanks

Comment: It would be a lot easier to diagnose the problems if you could post the `ui` file (or a pastebin link).

Comment: I'll post in the other thread

Answer (score 0):

The name of the widget can be set in the Property Editor with the `objectName` property. The class name (e.g. `QWidget`) cannot be changed.

The background colour can be set using the [setStyleSheet](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop) method.

Tip: A lot of these kinds of questions can answered by using pyuic4 to convert the `ui` file to a python module, so you can "see how its done". To do this, run the following command in a console:

```
pyuic4 -o output.py source.ui
```

The generated code is usually a lot more verbose than it needs to be, but it should give you a good idea of how to proceed.

Comment: The class I'm enclosing in the border has a changed class name, in this case the class is listed as DocumentView, even though it's a QWidget. In the program, the code which controls is is `class DocumentView(QWebView):`

Comment: Why do you care about the class names? What is the source of this `DocumentView` class? Is it a custom widget defined in a separate `ui` file?

Comment: At this point I only care out of curiosity. The only files DocumentView is mentioned in are the ui file and in the code.